# Why this data push to an array disappear after the forEach loop in the useEffect hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code

```
const Tabs = ({data, scrollX}) => {
  const [measures, setMeasures] = useState([]);
  const containerRef = useRef({});
  let measureMentArray = [];

useEffect(() => {
    data &&
      data.forEach(item =>  {
        item.ref.current.measureLayout(
          containerRef.current,
          (x, y, width, height) => {
            measureMentArray.push({x, y, width, height});
            // console.log(measureMentArray)
          },
        );
      });
    console.log(measureMentArray);
    // setMeasures(measureMentArray);
  }, []);
```

As you can see in my code. There is 2 `console.log` When I try to console `measureMentArray` in the first place the array will return 4 items. Its correct since data got 4 items.

But outside the forEach Loop, in the second console.log when I console `measureMentArray` The array is empty.

Is it because this is inside useEffect hooks? What can I do to set State after the loop end.

Comment: You can put `measureMentArray` in the empty `[]` at the end of useEffect.  That adds it as a *dependency* of the useEffect, and the useEffect will run again if that is what you want?

Comment: Which of your console statements logs first? Is measureLayout something async?

Answer (score -1):

forEach do something with every element in place, it doesn't mutate array, can use for i loop or better to use Array.map. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    cosnt newData = data &&
      data.map(item =>  {
        return item.ref.current.measureLayout(
          containerRef.current,
          (x, y, width, height) => ({x, y, width, height});
        );
      });
    if (newData && newData.length) {
      setMeasures(newData);
    }

  }, []);
```

Comment: ,the return statement is false. `return item.ref.current.measureLayout`
This will return all the things related to `measureLayout` which is not necessary and giving undefined when I start looping